# $http.get filter angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am accessing my data with

```
$http.get('/games').success(function(response){
    console.log("I got the data i requested");
    $scope.games = response;
})
```

then using

```
<tr ng-repeat="game in games | filter:query">
<td><a href="#/game/{{game._id}}">{{game.title}}</a></td>
<td>{{game.genre}}</td>
<td>{{game.developer}}</td>
```

to display the all the data in a list. If I now require to display a specific game using its ID how do I go about doing this? I have tried $http.get with params with no luck. how can I filter or query the $scope.games or retrieve specific data inside /games with $http.get.

Thank you

Comment: Is your back-end implemented that way ? Does it consider URL with `id` ?

Comment: It seems you don't need to fetch any additional data. Just get a specific element from games array and use it wherever you need it,  that depends on what structure you app has.

Comment: Which router are you using also? Most would use REST APi to retrieve the single item unless you have a service that stores all of them by default. Not really clear what your specific issue is

Comment: using angular route, yea i need specific elements from $scope.games but I'm struggling to see how to obtain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select required name="subCategory" ng-model="selectedSubCategoryIdToAdd" ng-change="GetSubCategoryId()" class="form-control" ng-options="subCategory as subCategory.SubCategoryName for subCategory in subCategories | filter : { CategoryId:selectedCategoryId }: true">
                    <option value="">Select SubCategory</option>
                </select>
```

This is how i did it with my example

For your example it can be done like this

```
<tr ng-repeat="game in games | filter: {game_id : 1} : true">
```

Comment: So you filtered in the HTML? How does this work? my data is current stored at  http://localhost:3000/games/

Comment: I can filter by somthing set in a controller yea? so if i set $scope.gameId = $routeParams.gameId; for example i can then filter: {{gameId}} : true ? allowing it to filter depending on what url is open?

Comment: Yes thats right. The variable you want to specify in filter must be there in the $scope of controller

Comment: Edit: I sorted it to work with words e.g. filter:{ 'genre':  'FPS'. but I dont know how to filter with {{gameTitle}} which if I call anywhere in the pages gives me the title of the game.

Comment: if you can filter with gameId then you should be able to filter with gameTitle as well